# Django: How to import a string variable into the django settings file from a middleware

Tags: python, django

I have a variable in my settings file, SITE_HOST_NAME, that I would want to dynamically change and update according to the current tenant domain, say, t1.leap.com. I have written a custom middleware that fetches the current tenant domain, the problem is appending the current tenant domain it generates to the settings file variable that is currently an empty string. nb: I am implementing multitenancy using Django tenants.

settings.py

```
SITE_HOST_SCHEMA = os.getenv('SITE_HOST_SCHEMA', 'http')
SITE_HOST_NAME = ''
SITE_HOST_PORT = os.getenv('SITE_HOST_PORT', 8000)
_default_siteurl = "%s://%s:%s/" % (SITE_HOST_SCHEMA,
                                    SITE_HOST_NAME,
                                    SITE_HOST_PORT) if SITE_HOST_PORT else "%s://%s/" % (
    SITE_HOST_SCHEMA, SITE_HOST_NAME)
SITEURL = os.getenv('SITEURL', _default_siteurl)
```

my_middleware.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import connection
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin as MIDDLEWARE_MIXIN
from django_tenants.utils import remove_www, get_tenant_model, get_public_schema_name
from customers.models import Domain


class CustomTenantMiddleware(MIDDLEWARE_MIXIN):
    def get_tenant(self, model, hostname, request):
        return model.objects.get(domain_url=hostname)

    def hostname_from_request(self, request):
        """ Extracts hostname from request. Used for custom requests filtering.
           By default removes the request's port and common prefixes.
       """
        return remove_www(request.get_host().split(':')[0]).lower()

    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            hostname = self.hostname_from_request(request)
            s = Domain.objects.get(domain=hostname)
            if s:
                settings.SITE_HOST_NAME = s.domain
                print(settings.SITE_HOST_NAME)
        except KeyError:
            pass  # use default urlconf (settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
```

Comment: settings value not supposed to be changed during the runtime.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I want the value to get the current domain name and set it before the settings file is run

Comment: just use .env file to store you variables and in settings file load this file and get variables from file

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen how will this be dynamic to ensure what is fetched from .env is similar to the current tenant domain name